# MVC App pointing to wrong hive(Registry)

Tags: iis, model-view-controller, regedit

In my MVC app i have the following code:

```
Private ipConecta As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SPR4", "ConnString", Nothing)
```

But looking in the Process monitor, i see that is pointing to another hive:

[image]

How can i make it pointing to read the registry on `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SPR4`

Comment: Are you sure that's not the correct hive? Who is the user ending in -1009? In PowerShell: `get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | where-object{$_.sidtype -eq 1} | Select Caption,SID` -1009 should be the user running your Application Pool.

Comment: Yes, it is actually point to that hive...the right hive for the app pool user...but i want to store my connection data in a reg file....so in another server that user should be different, and i want to have my reg file transparent...i try pointing it to HKLM, creating this key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\SPR4 SUCCESS`, but when y try to access it i got `NAME NOT FOUND`

Comment: Storing registry settings for IIS processes in user hives is asking for trouble, for reasons you are already seeing. You should try to fix your problem with HKLM, one reason could be that your application pool runs as 32bit process and would look at: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i resolve my issue, pointing to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`:

```
Private reg As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\SPR4")
```

And giving permissions on that key to the user `IUSR`.